# Adjective + preposition combination:

Tags: verbs

I find trouble to distinguish when to employ -ing or infinitive in certain cases. Have a look at the examples I came across on a book:
- Discover the secret to getting through to anyone.
- 7 steps to living at your full potential.

Based on that, I wonder if it's correct to say: discover the secret to GET, and 7 steps to LIVE. Why to use -ing after the preposition "to" in such cases? I know some verbs have the ing- form such as: look forward, dedicate, commit; but I've never seen "to getting" or "to living" after a noun as "secret" ot "steps".

I'm grateful in advance!

Comment: The present participle (...ing form) is idiomatic in the examples you give. *Discover the secret **of living** happily*; but *discover how **to live** happily*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The justification for using a participle with "to" is that  "to" here is a *preposition* which is followed by a noun, namely "getting" or "living". It is not meant as the *infinitive* "to".  And if it were, a different construction would be called for:

- Discover the secret of how to get through to anyone.
- Seven steps to help you {live up to/attain} your full potential

(live/living *at your potential* sounds odd)